# If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on an open set $U$ is it integrable over the surface of a submanifold contained in $U$?

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, surface-integrals

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $U\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open and $M\subseteq U$ be a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$

> Let $f\in\mathcal L^1(U)$ and $\sigma_M$ denote the surface measure on $\mathcal B(M)$. Are we able to show that $\left.f\right|_M\in\mathcal L^1(\sigma_M)$?

Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Maybe we can show $$\sigma_M(B)\le\lambda^{\otimes d}(B)\;\;\;\text{for all }B\in\mathcal B(M)\tag1$$ and use this to conclude the desired claim.

In this regard, we may note that, trivially, $U$ is a $d$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ and $$\sigma_U=\left.\lambda^{\otimes d}\right|_U\tag2.$$

*Remark*: It might be useful to note that there is the following characterization of the surface measure: $\sigma_M$ is the unique measure on $\mathcal B(M)$ with $$\left.\sigma_M\right|_\Omega=\sigma_\Omega\tag3$$ for every open subset (in the subspace topology) $\Omega$ of $M$.

Comment: Left and right derivative and continuity in a Banach space?

Comment: @MikaelHelin Sorry, what do you want to say?

Comment: Use Banach to show continuity in a point for the extended function $g$ and the same for its derivative.

Comment: @MikaelHelin You mean that I should prove that $g$ and $g'$ are continuous? I already know that. But how does that yield the claim?

Comment: Assume $f'(0)\neq g'(0)$ and then fail?

Comment: @MikaelHelin Assuming $f'(0)\neq g'(0)$ does not make sense, since I've *defined* $f'(0)$ to be $g'(0)$. What I would need to do is assuming that $\tilde g$ is another possible choice for $g$ with $g'(0)\ne\tilde g'(0)$ and then show that this is not possible.

Comment: @MikaelHelin Maybe I'm thinking to complicated. It should simply follow from $$g'(0)=\lim_{h\to0+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}h=\tilde g'(0),$$ right? I thought it would be a problem that $g$ and $\tilde g$ might differ on $(-\varepsilon,0)$, but I guess that doesn't effect their derivative at $0$, right?

Comment: The submanifold is of measure zero in $U$, so $f|_M$ seem to be not well-defined.

Comment: @ArcticChar Please explain how you interpret the notion of being "of measure zero in $U$". Do you mean that $\lambda^{\otimes d}(M)=0$? That doesn't need to hold when $k=d$. However, please note that I've taken $f$ from the semi-normed space $\mathcal L^1(U)$, not from the quotient space $L^1(U)$. So, $\left.f\right|_M$ is well-defined.

Comment: Just take $M= \mathbb R \times \{0\} \subset \mathbb R^2$ and define $f(x, y) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if } y\neq 0 , \\ \chi_E(x) &\text{ if } y=0.\end{cases}$, where $E\subset M$ is a non-measureable set. Then $f$ is integrable but $f|_M$ is not measureable.

Comment: @ArcticChar In total generality, if $f$ is a measurable function on a measurable space $(E,\mathcal E)$ and $B\in\mathcal E$, then $\left.f\right|_B$ is measurable with respect to the trace $\sigma$-algebra $\left.\mathcal E\right|_B$. In your example, $M$ is Borel measurable, but if $E$ is not Borel measurable, then $f$ is not Borel measurable and hence cannot be integrable.

Answer (score 2):

*sketch of a counterexample*:

Let $d=2$, $U=(-9,9)\times (-9,9)$ and let $M$ be the $1$-dimensional submanifold
which is described by the circle with radius $1$ and center $(1,0)$.
For the function $f$ we choose
$$
 f(x,y)=
 \begin{cases}
   x^{-2/3} &: x>0
\\
   0 &: x\leq 0
 \end{cases},
$$
where $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$.

Then one can show that $f\in L^1(U)$, but not $f\in L^1(\sigma_M)$.

(*hint*: for showing that $f\not\in L^1(\sigma_M)$
estimates of the form $c_1s^2\leq 1-\cos s \leq c_2 s^2$
can be useful for $s\in\mathbb R$ where $|s|$ is small.)

Comment: Can we at least show that the surface measure associated with a compact submanifold is finite?

Answer (score 1):

If $k<d$ the answer is no.   $M$ has full surface measure but which has zero Lebesgue measure, while for $U\setminus M$ it is the converse. So they are mutually singular. In particular, your inequality (1) does not hold. When $M$ is compact and $C^1$, it has finite surface measure since this will be the case locally  around each point in $M$ (and then use compactness).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You wrote that "if $k<d$, the answer is no", but it's not clear to me from your answer whether you mean that the claim is true when $k=d$. Regarding the remainder of your answer: In order to show that $\sigma_M$ is finite, we only need to assume that $M$ is bounded or am I missing something?